# Setting Wordpress Primary Menu Programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I currently have two menus created via the back end. I need to activate the menu based on the geo location, which I have aleady setup to set a default currency. The menu names in the backend are Main and Main International. Below is the code:

```
function geo_client_currency($client_currency){
$userInfo = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip();

if ($userInfo->country->isoCode == 'US'){
    $client_currency = 'USD'; //currency code
    }
else {
    $client_currency = 'INR';
}

return $client_currency;
}
```

So essentially what I need to do is set the Main menu for the US and Main International for anywhere outside the US. I have reviewed the Codex but not quite sure how to implement that the easiest way possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be something as easy as this in the template file (like `header.php`)?

```
<?php
    $userInfo = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip();
    if ( $userInfo->country->isoCode == 'US' ){
        wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 1));    //Change 1 to be the Main ID
    } else {
        wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 2)); //Change 2 to be the Main International ID
    }
?>
```

Comment: That seems like it will work, how can I retrieve my menu id for the menu I created in the back end?

Comment: Scratch that, I went ahead a used the 'menu' => 'Main' argument, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$userInfo = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip();

if ( $userInfo->country->isoCode == 'US' ){
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'nav-menu', 'menu'=> 'Main' , 'depth' => 3, 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'sf-menu', 'walker' => new thb_MegaMenu  ) );
} else {
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'nav-menu', 'menu'=> 'Main International' , 'depth' => 3, 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'sf-menu', 'walker' => new thb_MegaMenu  ) ); //Change 2 to be the Main International ID
}
```

?>